# Find sum of row items where the index contains a string

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

In python, I have a panda Data Frame named data. We have a row for each index. How can I find the sum of the values in the third column for all rows whose index contains a keyword 'key'?

I can do it by a for loop, but it is not smart:

```
count = 0
  for i in range(1,10):     
    if 'key' in data.index[i]:
       count += data.iloc[i,3]
```

Comment: where is your code and data?

Comment: @coldspeed it is general, we don't need a data and code.

Comment: Sorry, but if you want the right answer to your question, you'd better show some semblance of effort at having first solved your problem. If you can't put effort into writing a good question, it doesn't paint a good picture. Please look at how to provide a [mcve]. This _is_ your general example.

Comment: @coldspeed  please see my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `str.contains` and count the number of `True` cases:

```
count = data.loc[data.index.str.contains('key'), data.columns[3]].sum()
```